# How was the flammability of Velcro addressed after the Apollo 1 fire?

Tags: apollo-program, materials, fire, velcro

> In a spacecraft review meeting held with Shea on August 19, 1966 (a week before delivery [of Apollo 1]), the crew expressed concern about the amount of **flammable material** (mainly nylon netting and **Velcro**) in the cabin, which both astronauts and technicians found convenient for holding tools and equipment in place.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_1#Spacecraft_preparation

Considering how fastidious NASA became about fire prevention after the Apollo 1 accident, **what steps were taken to mitigate the flammability of Velcro?**  (For example, the type of material, amount used, etc.)

Comment: If they learned from it, that lesson was lost on the space shuttle folks. The cockpit was practically lined in it. I still remember smarting at losing software checkout time in the simulator to 'Velcro mods' time.  Check out all the blue Velcro in this pic of Endeavour https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/650294main_powerdown-cockpit.jpg

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Nor has SpaceX learned the flammability lesson.  [This picture](https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/images/dragon/interior_1.jpg) of Crew Dragon sure looks like it has a lot of combustible plastic.

Comment: @DrSheldon, you can't tell how combustible something is just by looking at it.  Ordinary plastic and plastic with a heavy mix of flame-retardants look the same.

Comment: Mark is right -- NASA changed from nylon to flame-retardent Nomex (nylon doped with Chlorine).

Comment: @aml are you claiming the Velcro in spacecraft cockpits is made of Nomex? If you can back that up, you should write an answer.

Comment: I'm fairly sure SOP at SpaceX is to not look at lessons learned by others @DrSheldon

Comment: Nomex isn't a Nylon variant. It's similar to Kevlar.